# Edited functions.php file in Wordpress; site is broken

Tags: wordpress

Please view the website here: www.TattiniBoots.com

While editing the functions.php file, I lost connection; and the site is now broken.

I do not have a backup; does anyone have any absolute recommendation?

Comment: Connect to the site via FTP. Download the file. Undo the changes. Reupload. Pat yourself in the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions.php file can always be found by FTPing into your site and navigating to:

```
wp-contents/themes/your-theme-name/functions.php
```

I would always encourage you to perform edits to your site, particularly your functions.php file, on a development/staging platform.  Editing these files on your live site can, as you experienced, result in downtime should you make a mistake.